# How to POST a href link with isset

Tags: php, session, post, href, isset

Please help me, I wanted to do a post method using an anchor tag.
Here is the sample code:

```html
<form action="essay2.php" id="quiz" name="quiz" method="post">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="essay2.php" name="submit-test">2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" name="test1">
</form>
```

And the PHP code:

```php
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit-test'])) {
    $_SESSION['test1'] = $_POST['test1'];
    header("Location: essay2.php"]);
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code has errors. Btw, why would you want to do what you want?

Comment: _sidenote_: the header redirect after the echo won't work.

Comment: they edited @Jeff and Phil did a rollback just now. I wonder how many more edits this will go through *lol!* There's been 6 now.

Comment: I'm sorry for the wrong code - done editing. What I want is I want to do a Post Method not by button but using an anchor tag, then pass the input type POST to SESSION.

Comment: an anchor tag `<a>` won't send anything with a form. So `$_POST['submit-test']` will never be set. Again (as Funk said): what's the usecase for this?

Comment: You can actually style a `<button type="submit" name="submit-test">2</button>` element to look exactly like a plain text link. See Bootstrap's [_link_ button](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#examples) for an example. I'd give that a try if this is purely for the UI. Otherwise, you'll need to involve some JS to have an anchor submit a form

Comment: _or_ add a param to your href `href="essay2.php?submittest=true"` and check for `$_GET['submittest']` to see if the link was clicked. _BUT_ then 'test1' won't be sent along.

Comment: Just use Javascript. Put a click event on the anchor link. Then create a new `FormData` object passing the form towards it. After that, just submit it with js.

Comment: I see... Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I've already tried to use this: onclick="document.getElementById('quiz').submit();" but it doesn't get the $_POST['test1'];

Comment: Or how can I pass the $_POST['test1'] to $_SESSION['test1'] using the anchor tag ?

Comment: That's because your form doesn't have an `id` attribute with value `quiz`. It would also not include the `submit-test` parameter

Comment: No.. Just do `onclick='submitMyForm()'`. Then create a JS function: `function submitMyForm(){ var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('quiz')); .... etc }`

Comment: @icecub why? Seems redundant

Comment: This question's starting to look too broad and unclear, given what the new goal is.

Comment: @Phil No perticular reason. It's the way I would handle it, but that's because I use ajax all the time. Commented out of habit I guess

Comment: @Phil On the bright side, a `FormData` object can be manipulated. It would be possible to add the `submit-test` to it inside JS.

Comment: @icecub but difficult to submit naturally (easy for AJAX though)

Comment: @Phil True, I don't believe it was intended to be used without Ajax. My bad there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment above...

> You can actually style a `<button type="submit" name="submit-test">2</button>` element to look exactly like a plain text link

consider this approach

```css
button[name="submit-test"] {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form action="essay2.php" id="quiz" name="quiz" method="post">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button name="submit-test" type="submit">2</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" name="test1">
</form>
```

Results in the following sent when you click the *"2"*

[image: Network console]

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript with the onclick method on your link.

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();">click to send</a>
```

You also need to put a id to your form tag (id="myform" in this case).

This is how I would do:

```
<form action="essay2.php" id="quiz" name="quiz" method="post">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('quiz').submit();">2</a>          
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" name="test1">
  <input type="hidden" name="submit-test">
</form>
```

Comment: One problem with this... This won't send the `submit-test` parameter which OP's PHP relies on

Comment: Thanks for that, But I want to pass the $_POST['test1'] to $_SESSION['test1'] using the POST method.

Comment: @CarloMontemayor this will most certainly do that

Comment: Not really since it's testing if the index `submit-test` exists instead of `test1`, which makes no sense. That has to be fixed too.

Comment: if you want to pass the submit-test parameter, just add a hidden input named submit-test to the form

Answer (score 0):

Use the tag inside the like this :

```
<button type="submit" name="submit-test"><a href="essay2.php"> 2  </button>
```